# Issue with CLI on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

Wondering if anyone has any thoughts about this. When I try to redirect stdout in my WSL terminal I get an error about having an open pipe. But I can run the same command from Git Bash without any problems.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how 
I might get around this?

I am not a Linux power user by any stretch. I saw that this was an issue marked as closed on the WSL Github https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2370

Not sure if the fault lies with WSL or the user. Redirect works if I am not using SF commands.  echo hello > hello.txt works just fine.

```
brooksdjohnson@DESKTOP-L4C7EFO:~$ sfdx force:data:soql:query -q 'SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM COntact Limit 20' -u uber > test.csv
net.js:268
    err = this._handle.open(fd);
                       ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (net.js:268:24)
    at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:191:18)
    at process.getStderr [as stderr] (internal/process/stdio.js:32:14)
    at console.js:455:19
    at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:364:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:176:18)
    at setupGlobalConsole (internal/bootstrap/node.js:407:41)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:142:7)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: The [official line on using the CLI in WSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_windows) is that `The Salesforce CLI works best within the native Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) and the Microsoft Powershell. We do not recommend using the Salesforce CLI with a Linux terminal emulator, such as Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux, cygwin, or MinGW, because support for bugs is limited.`. Do you have the CLI installed through WSL (ie, using the Linux commands from the install page)?

Comment: Hmmm, no I never installed it that way. My Ubuntu terminal always picked it up so I never worried about it.

Comment: I'm not saying that that **would** fix it, but it might. I've not tried the SF CLI in WSL, ever, and haven't used WSL at all of late. Last time I actively used it was before it would run Win executables, & so I had to install the Linux tools to run them. Not sure how it resolves conflicts when the same command is on your Linux path and your Win path.

Comment: I installed it on my WSL but it is not finding any of my dev hubs or scratch org. And force:auth:web:loging is timing out.

Comment: Right, so the WSL-installed version isn't pointed to all the same config folders (it's basically like having an installation on a different computer) -- that might be fixable, but I'm not certain how. The Win-installed version doesn't act right with some WSL functions like `stdout` redirection. Hence SF's recommendation against.